# How to run a .bat file in task scheduler

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I have a .bat file that is one line long and calls up a vb script that specifically opens an excel file and runs some macros:

```
cscript priordays.vbs "C:\PATHANME\FILENAME.xlsm"
```

When I run it by double clicking, it runs fine and successfully.

When I run in task scheduler, it says it ran successfully (code 0x0), but the script does not execute.  I've got it set to run with highest permissions, regardless of whether or not the user is logged in, wake machine, etc.  Still nothing.

For those asking what's in the vb script, it's:

```
Dim arts, objExcel

Set args = WScript.ARguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.visible = True

objExcel.Run "Macro1"
objExcel.Run "Macro2"
objExcel.Run "Macro3"

objWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Quit
```

I found that code elsewhere on this site, along with the instructions on using the .bat file.  If there's a way to run it all from the script, and try to launch the script from task scheduler, I'm fine to do that as well.

Comment: Give me two minutes. :)

Comment: Does not seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Set the 'start in' location to the script location and ensure the permissions on that folder allow the account running the task to execute the batch file.

Comment: It's an administrator account, so it has full permissions, changing start in location has not changed anything.

Comment: Try running it as yourself first, not as an elevated or admin user.

Comment: Running it as myself works fine. It's running it through task scheduler that's the problem.

Comment: No, I mean running it thru task scheduler but using your account

Comment: I'm afraid I do not follow. I'm opening task scheduler while logged in as me.  How is that not using my account?

Comment: Why aren't you just running the Vbscript directly?

Comment: I'm saying to set the task to run under your user account, and to disable elevated permissions, ie ensuring it runs under your auth and permissions.

Comment: I don't know how to set the vb script to look at the right file.  I've posted it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running batch files and/or vbs from a scheduled task, the full file path and filename must be declared.

If a file system object is used to get a filname, then passed (without the path) to a function that interacts with the file it will work from a double click, but not as a scheduled task.

Can you try with the full path and in the .vbs file?

Does your scheduled task launch excel, but not run the excel macro, or does it not even launch excel?

Comment: It does not even launch excel.

Comment: Is the full filepath / name specified? Can you provide a snip of your batch file code, obviously with the names changes etc.

Comment: All code has been added to the main question.

Comment: Is the 'typo' actually in your file?   You are dimming 'arts' but setting 'args'.  Dim arts, objExcel
 
Set args = WScript.ARguments

Comment: Your code:    objExcel.Run "Macro1"  Assumes that your macro is in a module rather than one of the sheets.  Is your macro actually in a module, or is it in a sheet?  If it is in a sheet you will need to specify this in your ObjExcel.Run.... i.e. objExcel.Run "'xxxx.xls'!sheet1.Macro1".  Note the single quotes surrounding the filename.

Comment: It is in a module.  And the program works when I double click the .bat file.  It's just when I try to run it from task scheduler that it fails.

Comment: Can you fill in the 'Start in (optional)' field in Task Scheduler.

Right click your task in Scheduler >> Properties >> Actions >> Edit >> 'Start in (optional)' is at the bottom.

Put the path to your .bat file in here.

Comment: Tried that one. Didn't have any effect, sadly.

Comment: There are 3 other things to try: 1.) Make sure that the task is running under an account that has 'Full access' to a.) the .bat file b.) the folder containing the .bat file c.) the xlsm target file and folder.
2.) Ensure the account running the task is a member of the local 'administrators' group for the machine
3.) Remove any spaces or special characters from any paths / name

Comment: It ended up working by telling task scheduler to open excel, and then to open the file, and having an auto_open macro that ran everything I needed.